# Is $\mathbb C^3\cong \mathbb ℝ^6$?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Question: If $\mathbb C$ naturally has a bijection with $\mathbb R^2$ (and has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$), can I just assume:

- That $\mathbb C^3$ has a bijection with an $\mathbb R^6$

and

- they also have $\mathbb R$ cardinality?

Comment: yes to both is the short answer

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by: "Can I just assume..." If you are in a class covering elementary set theory, you might be expected to prove these claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you can figure out why $\mathbb{C}^3$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{R}^6$ (extend the bijection from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ appropriately).

We want to show that for any integer $n$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$. By induction, it is sufficient to show that $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bijection. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Write $x=(x_1,...x_{n+1})$. Then $g:\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $g(x)=(x_1,...,x_{n-1},f(x_n,x_{n+1})$) is a bijection and we're done. Is that clear enough?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I didn't realize it was so elementary.